# Tkinter - How to update text after select option in dropdown menu?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a menu in Tkinder. This menu consists of several submenus.
I built a structure with for loop for the formation of these menus.
However, I could not make the menu button update according to the selection

Example code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.categories = {
            "A": {
                "B": {
                    "C": {},
                    "D": {},
                },
                "E": {
                    "F": {}
                }
            },
            "G": {}
        }

        self.menu_button = ttk.Menubutton(master, text = "Select")
        self.top_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu_button, tearoff = False)
        self.menu_button.configure(menu = self.top_menu)
        self.create_category_menu(self.categories, self.top_menu)

        self.menu_button.pack()

    # I created a recursive function, constantly checking subcategories
    def create_category_menu(self, categories, top_menu):
        for category in categories:
            if (len(categories[category]) == 0):
                # if the category has no subcategories, just add the name
                top_menu.add_cascade(label = category)
            else:
                # If there are subcategories, create a separate menu for subcategories
                # and insert it into the top menu
                menu = tk.Menu(top_menu)
                top_menu.add_cascade(label = category, menu = menu)
                self.create_category_menu(categories[category], menu)

root = tk.Tk()
window = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The code creates the menus as I want, but I cannot write the selected option to the button

```
top_menu.add_cascade(label = category, command = self.func(category))

top_menu.add_cascade(label = category, menu = menu, command = self.func(category))
```

I changed these two lines like this, I also created the following function in the code;

```py
def func(self, category):
        self.menu_button["text"] = category
```

This time, it writes the bottom value of the category dictionary ("G") to the button.

There are 97 nested categories. The code above is an example I prepared for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command` requires a *callable* (ie: a function). When you do something like `command = self.func(category)` you are immediately calling `self.func(category)` and passing the result to the `command` option.

A simple solution is to use `lambda`, which creates a new function from which you can call your function. You can bind the current value of `category` to the function through the use of default arguments.

```
...
def func(self, category):
    print(f"func called with '{category}'")

def create_category_menu(self, categories, top_menu):
    for category in categories:
        if (len(categories[category]) == 0):
            top_menu.add_command(label=category, command=lambda c=category: self.func(c))
        else:
            ...
...
```